# ProxyPass a WebSocket connection to a UNIX socket

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, socket, proxypass, websocket

In Apache 2.4 you can reverse proxy an **HTTP** connection to a local **Unix** socket with: [[1]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)

```
ProxyPass unix:/path/to/app.sock|http://example.com/app/name
```

You can reverse proxy a **WebSocket** connection to a local **TCP** socket with: [[2]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)

```
ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:12345/app/name
```

But how can you reverse proxy a **WebSocket** connection to a **Unix** socket? [☹]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got it, once you have `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_wstunnel` enabled you can do this:

```
ProxyPass /ws/ unix:/path/to/app.sock|ws://example.com/ws/
```

It works well for me since I only expect to establish a ws connection on the `/ws` endpoint.